# Правильность написания программы и как сделать переходы при нажатии на кавишу

Tags: java

В java новичок.Прошу оценить правильность написания кода и подскажите как сделать переходы с открытием нового окна при нажатии на кнопку(при этом старое закрывается) и обратно.За ранние всем спасибо!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class Authorization{


    public void createGui(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Поисковая система Личностей");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(400,200);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        JTextField field = new JTextField("Введите логин");
        field.setBounds(90,20,200,30);
        JPasswordField passwordField = new JPasswordField("Введите пароль");
        passwordField.setBounds(90,60,200,30);
        passwordField.getPassword();

        panel.add(field);
        panel.add(passwordField);


        JButton bRegistrate = new JButton("Регистрация");
        bRegistrate.setBounds(90,100,120,30);
        JButton  bVhod= new JButton("Вход");
        bVhod.setBounds(220,100,70,30);
        panel.add(bRegistrate);
        panel.add(bVhod);


        bVhod.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (bVhod == e.getSource()){
                    BaseShow baseShow = new BaseShow();
                    baseShow.display();

                }
            }
        });

        bRegistrate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (bRegistrate == e.getSource()){
                    BaseRegistraction baseRegistraction = new BaseRegistraction();
                    baseRegistraction.registr();
                }
            }
        });
        frame.validate();
        frame.repaint();
    }
}

import javax.swing.*;

public class BaseRegistraction {
    public void registr(){
        JFrame frameReg = new JFrame("Регистрация");
        frameReg.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frameReg.setVisible(true);
        frameReg.setResizable(false);
        frameReg.setSize(500,500);
        frameReg.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Код должен быть в самом вопросе, а не на гугле диске.